# Audio message in JSQMessagesViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, avaudioplayer, jsqmessagesviewcontroller

Recently i completed chat using JSQMessagesViewController and its working fine for Video, Image & Text. Now, I want to implement Audio message for existing JSQMessagesViewController. Is there anyone who implemented audio message for the same ?

I just got the link 
https://github.com/jessesquires/JSQMessagesViewController/issues/1049 in that there is file EXTJSQMediaMessage.swift but i didn't find it helpful.

Please help me how to implement this feature ?

Comment: Did you solve this ?

Comment: Did you solve your problem? If yes can you post your code, it can help other, thank you

Comment: Did you get any solution for your problem? is record and send audio functionality like WhatsApp available in this library because I didn't find it in the library's document.